# read selected data from multiple databases in php

Tags: php, mysql

So this is my query, it selects data from 3 tables on 2 different databases:

```
SELECT r.id AS id, r.idAccount AS idAccount, r.name AS name, r.surname AS surname, r.company AS company, r.`date` AS date, r.callback_date AS callback_date, u.user_owner_id, c.name
FROM D045618D.`requests_free_demos` AS r
LEFT JOIN D045617D.`user_accounts` AS u ON r.`idAccount` = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN D045618D.`cmsUsers` AS c ON u.`user_owner_id` = c.`id` 
WHERE c.`id` = " . $GLOBALS['cmsUser']->id
```

Now I need to execute that query with PHP. The problem is that I have to open 2 databases at the same time, anyone knows how to do that?

Is it even possible, or are there maybe better ways to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: This should work straight away. Did you try it e.g. with `mysql_query()`? What error did you get?

Comment: What do you mean 2 databases open at the same time?  MySQL can support cross-schema queries on the same server.  So do you mean multiple `servers`?  Or multiple schemas?

Comment: I'm assuming you are already ensuring that $GLOBALS['cmsUser']->id is an integer? If not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to open two databases. Just do the `mysql_connect` and run the query by `mysql_query`. It will work fine.

**As long as (1) all table names are completely referenced with database name, (2) Both databases are on same server, and (3) the user has access to both DBs**, you do not need to do `mysql_select_db` on it. All such queries will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are both databases on the same server?
As others already said you should not have any problem then.
If the two databases are on two different servers the only solution I can think of is creating federated tables one one server to access the other.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html

To put it simple: 
Federated tables allow you to thread remote tables as local tables.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, if they are on the same server, and you have the proper permissions, and you prefix each table name with the correct database name (which you are doing) you can just feed this to one mysql connection. No need to open 2 databases; you only open a connection to the server.